# How to reduce PHP FPM and MySQL memory usage in Debian 9

Tags: php, mysql, linux, nginx, memory

I'm managing a server on AWS, `t2.micro` (1 Mem GiB) instance type with Debian 9.

Main services installed are:

- Nginx (active)
- MySQL (active)
- **Supervisor (stopped)**
- Redis (active)

> These programs are for 10 Laravel (PHP) projects enabled.

The problem is that free memory is always between 60MB-75MB and I can't even start `supervisor` service or install new project dependencies via `composer` without crashing everything (including SSH session):

```
$ free -m

              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            994         477          71         140         444         233
Swap:             0           0           0
```

The processes consuming memory are:

```
$ ps aux  | awk '{print $6/1024 " MB\t\t" $11}'  | sort -n

...
10.9492 MB      php-fpm:
104.473 MB      php-fpm:
120.109 MB      php-fpm:
144.262 MB      php-fpm:
380.344 MB      /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

Actually I have only 2 MySQL (not large) databases. Why MySQL is consuming 380MB? There's a way to optimise it?

And what about PHP-FPM, there is a need to run 4 different processes with ~100MB each? How to reduce this?

Answer (score 0):

Default MySQL settings are optimized and suitable for general situations. If it consumes 380 MB (in our days it is a small amount of memory), it is probably normal. Still, you could make some things with MySQL:

1. use MyISAM instead of InnoDB (you could turn off InnoDB engine - refer to MySQL docs)
2. Change some memory caches parameters (please refer to http://www.tocker.ca/2014/03/10/configuring-mysql-to-use-minimal-memory.html and MySQL documentation) but in this case, you might get performance degradation of your MySQL server.

Best of all is to use cheaper hosting because AWS is overpriced. You can buy more powerful server for the same money.